# Rails Tutorial 7.4.4 - How does post method submit form with authenticity token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, csrf, restful-url

I'm at [Rails Tutorial 7.4.4](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-a_test_for_valid_submission) and I'm curious about how the `post_via_redirect` method in the following test post  form along with `authenticity_token` parameter.

The following test would pass:

```
class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "valid signup information will add user to database" do
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post_via_redirect users_path, user: { name: "Filius Flitwick",
                               email: "Filius_Flitwick@Hogworts.ORG",
                               password:                "charmsmaster",
                               password_confirmation:   "charmsmaster" }
    end
  end
end
```

In order to prevent CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery), I assume that the form won't pass the verification without a correct `authenticity_token` parameter in the form. However, I cannot figure out from where the  `authenticity_token` is put into the `parameters`.

In fact I'm not sure what exactly the `POST` in rails is doing. Would `POST` first request a web page of the URL to get the `authenticity_token`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the CSRF protection is disabled in the test environment. You can activate it by adding the following line in `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = true
```

See the guide on [Configuration Rails Application](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-controller).

Comment: I think that's exactly the answer. Thanks!